# Data not getting fetched from sqlite to list view - android

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

I wrote a code to fetch the data from `sqlite` to `ListView`.

```
ArrayList<feedWord> words = new ArrayList<feedWord>();
        ForumDbHelper helper = new ForumDbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        String projection[] = {
                ForumContract.ForumEntry.COLUMN_TITLE,
                ForumContract.ForumEntry.COLUMN_USER,
                ForumContract.ForumEntry.COLUMN_DATE,
                ForumContract.ForumEntry.COLUMN_STATUS
        };
        String selection = ForumContract.ForumEntry.COLUMN_STATUS + "=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {"1"};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(ForumContract.ForumEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null);
        try {
            int userColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ForumContract.ForumEntry.COLUMN_USER);
            int dateColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ForumContract.ForumEntry.COLUMN_DATE);
            int titleColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ForumContract.ForumEntry.COLUMN_TITLE);
            while(cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                String userID = cursor.getString(userColumnIndex);
                String date = cursor.getString(dateColumnIndex);
                String title = cursor.getString(titleColumnIndex);
                words.add(new feedWord(title,userID,date));
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        feedAdapter itemsAdapter = new feedAdapter(this,words);
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

**feedWord**

```
public class feedWord {
    private String question;
    private String username;
    private String date;

    public feedWord(String fquestion, String fusername, String fdate)
    {
        question = fquestion;
        username = fusername;
        date = fdate;
    }

    public String getQuestion()
    {
        return question;
    }

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public String getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }
}
```

However this code doesn't fetch the data from sqlite. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure your query into the database returns result? I mean the words ArrayList is probably empty

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for reference in reading data from SQLite, it will help you.

I have created a simple android activity with its layout, the layout file contains `<ListView>` as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".All">

   <ListView
      android:id="@+id/studentListView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:layout_margin="20dp">
   </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code for All.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class All extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    StudentAdapter adapter;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.studentListView);

        students = databaseHelper.getStudents();

        adapter = new StudentAdapter(this, students);

       listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

I also created a model java class and the code is as follows
Student.java

```
public class Student {
    String firstname;
    String lastname;

    public Student(String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
}
```

Then i created the StudentAdapter together with its xml layout and the code is as follows
StudentAdapter.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import java.util.List;

public class StudentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Student> {
    Activity context;
    List<Student> students;

    public StudentAdapter(Activity context, List<Student> students) {
        super(context, R.layout.view_student, students);
        this.context = context;
        this.students = students;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_student,  null, true);
        TextView name = view.findViewById(R.id.f_name);
        TextView surname = view.findViewById(R.id.l_name);

        name.setText(students.get(position).getFirstname());
        surname.setText(students.get(position).getLastname());

     return view;
    }
}
```

view_student.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/f_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/l_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
        
    </LinearLayout>

  </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then finally the method that reads data from SQIite in the DatabaseHelper.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //database name
    public static final String databaseName = "example.db";

    //table name and columns
    public static final String studentTable = "students";
    public static final String student_name = "student_name";
    public static final String student_surname = "student_surname";

    //constructor
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, databaseName, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + studentTable + "(" + student_name + " TEXT," + student_surname + " TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + studentTable);
    }

    //insert method
    public boolean insertStudent(String name, String surname) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(student_name, name);
        contentValues.put(student_surname, surname);
        long result = db.insert(studentTable, null, contentValues);
      return result != -1;
    }

    //read method
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor row = db.query(studentTable, new String[]{student_name, student_surname}, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (row.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!row.isAfterLast()) {
                String name = row.getString(row.getColumnIndex(student_name));
                String surname = row.getString(row.getColumnIndex(student_surname));
                students.add(new Student(name, surname));
                row.moveToNext();
            }
        }
       return students;
    }
}
```